# ngModel hacia un objeto Angular5

Tags: angular5, ionic3, ecmascript-6

me encuentro en un lió y espero puedan ayudarme a resolverlo. 
Tengo un objeto en mi `pagina.ts` el cual es el siguiente

```
 datos:[{
    tipo_persona:string,
    identificacion:number,
    nombre:string,
    apellido:string,
    razon_social:string,
    fecha_nacimiento:string,
    genero:string,
    ocupacion:string,
    telefono:string,
    operadora:string,
    correo:string,
    correo2:string,
    sitio_web:string,
    pais:string,
    provincia:string,
    ciudad:string,
    ciudadela:string,
    calle1:string,
    calle2:string,
    codigo_postal:number,
    Proposito:string[],
    clave:string,
    clave2:string,
    pregunta1:string,
    respuesta1:string,
    pregunta2:string,
    respuesta2:string,
    pregunta3:string,
    respuesta3:string
  }];
```

y desde mi `pagina.html` intento ingresarle los valores a ciertos elementos de mi objeto de la siguiente manera

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div class="labelTittle">
        <ion-label>
            Informacion Personal
        </ion-label>
    </div>
    <ion-item no-lines>
        <ion-label>Tipo Persona</ion-label>
        <ion-select class="input-label" placeholder="Tipo Persona" [(ngModel)]="datos.tipo_persona">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let item of tipo" [value]="item.descripcion">{{item.descripcion}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="input" *ngIf="persona == 'Natural'">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Identificación" [(ngModel)]="datos.identificacion" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombres" [(ngModel)]="datos.nombre" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" [(ngModel)]="datos.apellido" />
        <input placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date" [(ngModel)]="datos.fecha_nacimiento">

        <ion-row radio-group class="label" [(ngModel)]="datos.genero">
            <ion-col>
                <ion-item no-lines>
                    <ion-radio slot="start" value="M">Prueba</ion-radio>
                    <ion-label>Hombre</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-item no-lines class="label">
                    <ion-radio slot="start" value="F"></ion-radio>
                    <ion-label>Mujer</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label>Ocupación</ion-label>
            <ion-select class="input-label" placeholder="Ocupación">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let item of ocup" [value]="item.descripcion">{{item.descripcion}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
    </div>
    <div class="input" *ngIf="persona == 'Juridico'">
        <input type="text" placeholder="RUC/Identificación" [(ngModel)]="datos.identificacion" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Razón Social" [(ngModel)]="datos.razon_social" />
    </div>
    <ion-fab bottom right>
        <button color="invi" ion-fab (click)="navPage()"><ion-icon name="ios-arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

he intentato varias maneras, pero no doy, la idea es llenar ciertos elementos del objeto, pero enviarlo a otra pagina y llenar los elementos que esa otra pagina me indique, se que se ve ridículo, ¿por qué no llenar todos los elementos en una sola pagin? lo mismo me pregunte yo, pero lamentamente así es el proyecto.

solo me falta ingresarle los datos al objeto y listo.

Les agradezco de antemano el tiempo que se tomen en brindar su apoyo.

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el problema. ¿Qué error tienes? ¿Por qué es problemático tener un formulario repartido en dos pantallas? Esto último es habitual si es un formulario muy largo, en las SPA se suele evitar tener que usar el scroll

Comment: en mi primera pantalla guardo los 8 primeros elementos de de objeto, eliminare los corchetes, no se como acceder a los datos del objeto con el ngModal, me sale que el tipo_persona no ha sido definida, como guardo estos datos en mi objeto para que en la siguiente pantalla guardar los siguientes elemento, ojo, se como enviar datos de una pantalla a otra

Answer (score 0):

Si no he entendido mal tu pregunta quieres saber cómo pasar objetos de una página a otra ¿no?

Si es así lo puedes hacer de muchas formas:
Pasándolo como navParam, en la funcion que usas navPage() supongo que cargarás la página siguiente, ahí puedes pasarle "datos" como parámetro:

```
this.navCtrl.push(page, {"datos":datos})
```

Y después lo puedes recuperar con navParams:

```
private datos:any;
constructor(public navParams: NavParams){
   // userParams is an object we have in our nav-parameters
   this.datos = this.navParams.get('userParams');
 }
```

Otra opción es usar un servicio que almacene el objeto:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

También puedes guardar el objeto en localStorage y recuperarlo después, o incluso utilizar eventos que escriban/lean el objeto...

También veo que has declarado tu objeto como un array, si tu problema es que no se está guardando el objeto es por eso, te sobran los corchetes en la declaración del objeto, con los corchetes estás declarando un array de objetos:

```
datos:{
    tipo_persona:string,
    identificacion:number,
    nombre:string,
    apellido:string,
    razon_social:string,
    fecha_nacimiento:string,
    genero:string,
    ocupacion:string,
    telefono:string,
    operadora:string,
    correo:string,
    correo2:string,
    sitio_web:string,
    pais:string,
    provincia:string,
    ciudad:string,
    ciudadela:string,
    calle1:string,
    calle2:string,
    codigo_postal:number,
    Proposito:string[],
    clave:string,
    clave2:string,
    pregunta1:string,
    respuesta1:string,
    pregunta2:string,
    respuesta2:string,
    pregunta3:string,
    respuesta3:string
  };
```

Espero que alguna de las opciones arroje luz a tu problema.
Un saludo.

Comment: no es mi pregunta, se como enviar parametros de una pantalla a otra, lo que quiero es que con el ngModel accedar a los datos del objeto

Comment: Si miras la segunda parte creo que es el problema que estas teniendo, no accedes con el ngModel porque tu estas buscando "datos.nombre" la estructura que has puesto de objeto es un array datos=[{...}] tienes o bien que modificar la estructura quitando los corchetes datos={...} o si realmente querías que fuese un array puedes o recorrerlocon ngFor o bien usar "datos[0].nombre"